# Typescript: Receiving errors when typing an object or array as rxjs Subject variable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

My snippet.

```
signUpInfo: {code: string, message: string} 
     = new Subject<{code: string, message: string}>();
```

The error Atom editor gives me.

> Type 'Subject<{code: string, message: string}>' is not assignable to
>   type '{code: string, message: string}'. Property 'code' is missing in
>   type 'Subject<{code: string, message: string}>'.

[image: typescript error]

Removing the typings in the variable, replacing by type `any` or `{}` removes the error.

```
signUpInfo = new Subject<{code: string, message: string}>();
signUpInfo: any = new Subject<{code: string, message: string}>();
signUpInfo: {} = new Subject<{code: string, message: string}>();
signUpInfo = new Subject<{code: string, message: string}>();
signUpInfo: any[] = new Subject<model[]>();
```

I am used to put a typeings on every variable in TS, I have no problems when passing regular types such as string number booleans etc. but when passing array or object as Subject variable typings it seems that Im not allowed to it.

What is the correct way of typing an object or array Subject variable in typescript?

Comment: A Subject<Message> is like a phone: it **emits** messages. A phone is not a message. The type of your variable should be the type you used on the right side of the equal sign: Subject<{code: string, message: string}>

Comment: I see thanks @JBNizet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way is to set:

```
signUpInfo: Subject<{code: string, message: string}> = new Subject<{code: string, message: string}>();
```

Actually I think you don't even need to set the type because it's automatically assumed when you're assigning it an instance of `Subject<{code: string, message: string}>`. So if you try to call `signUpInfo.next(1)` the compiler will throw a type error.

Comment: Thank you now i get it why there are a lot subject variable snippets having no typings